# Port not available. Exiting... for golang selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, go

I use [selenium golang webdriver](https://github.com/fedesog/webdriver) example.

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/fedesog/webdriver"
    "log"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    chromeDriver := webdriver.NewChromeDriver("/path/To/Chrome/Driver/chromedriver")
    err := chromeDriver.Start()
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
    desired := webdriver.Capabilities{"Platform": "Linux"}
    required := webdriver.Capabilities{}
    session, err := chromeDriver.NewSession(desired, required)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
    err = session.Url("http://golang.org")
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
    time.Sleep(10 * time.Second)
    session.Delete()
    chromeDriver.Stop()
}
```

It works but logs error:

```
Port not available. Exiting..
```

Full output is :

```
Starting ChromeDriver (v2.9.248307) on port 9515
Port not available. Exiting...
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks as though the fedesog/webdriver is trying to open up a listener on port 9515 and that is failing:

https://github.com/fedesog/webdriver/blob/master/chromedriver.go

You could try switching ports or seeing what if anything might be blocking that port on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check chromedriver log or run it from console.

It maybe some package dependencies like dbus.